# How to extract the column in csv in python

Tags: python, csv, tkinter, listbox

I am using python and csv lib and Tkinter GUI

```
Column1    Column2
Test1      ID1
           ID2
           ID3
Test2      Act1
           ACT2
           ACT3
```

I want to show the column2 as per the Column1 Test no. 
For example :SO Test1 is selected ID1 , ID2, ID3 should be shown and in next iteration When Test2 is selected Act1, Act2, Act3 is shown

What I tried:

```
with open('Test.csv') as f:
  listbox = tk.Listbox(self.root, width=162, height=200)
  listbox.place(x=10, y=50)
  reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=',')
  for row in reader:
    adata1 = row['column1']
    adata2 = row['column2']

    if adata1 != adata1 or adata1 == "":
      listbox.insert('end', adata2)
    else:
      continue
```

Please if anyone can help me.

Comment: First fix the indentation of your code.  Second your question is not clear.  How do you select `Test1` or `Test2`? In a `Listbox`?  What will be the final content of `listbox` you expect? What is your current issue actually?

Comment: adata1 = row['column1'] this will select Test1 , In Listbox ID1, ID2,ID3 should be shown, in next for Loop adata1 = Test2 Listbox will show Act1, Act2, Act3

Comment: According to what you explain, the final content of `listbox` will be `Act1`, `Act2` and `Act3`, right?  You will never see `ID1`, `ID2` and `ID3` as they will be replaced.

Comment: it should be replaced as per the test1 and test2

Comment: I have right key which will select the Test1 and Test2. If Test1 will selected ID1,ID2,ID3 will be shown and when again right arrow key pressed it will show Test2 and Act1, Act2,Act3 will be shown

Comment: I am stuck I dont know how can  I display the content of Column2 based on Test1 and Test2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my understanding, the content of `Test.csv` file is something like:

```
column1,column2
Test1,ID1
,ID2
,ID3
Test2,ACT1
,ACT2
,ACT3
```

Then you can use a dictionary to store the CSV file content:

```py
import csv

tests = {}
with open('Test.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        if row['column1']:
            key = row['column1']
            tests[key] = []
        tests[key].append(row['column2'])
```

And the result of `tests` will be:

```
{'Test1': ['ID1', 'ID2', 'ID3'], 'Test2': ['ACT1', 'ACT2', 'ACT3']}
```

And you can populate the required items into `listbox` based on your selected key:

```
listbox = tk.Listbox(self.root, width=162, height=200)
listbox.place(x=10, y=50)

...

key = 'Test1' # assume Test1 is selected as the key

listbox.delete(0, 'end')
for item in tests[key]:
    listbox.insert('end', item)
```